# conversion data with erlang

Tags: erlang

my question now is :

I have the variavle M which contains :  37.5  (as you see is integer)

I want to convert M in order to be string  "37.5"

so    37.5   should became   "37.5"

I try with function :

```
 M2=integer_to_list(M)
```

but when I execute this function it displays this error :

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  integer_to_list/1
        called as integer_to_list(37.5)
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, which is why you are getting downvoted.

Comment: Please edit your question, not just add comments. And why `45250` will become `452500`?

Comment: Of course you can't do that. `37.5` is a float number!

Answer (score 1):

integer_to_list wont work in that situation because 37.5 is a float and not an integer. Erlang does have float_to_list, but the output is usually pretty unusable.

Instead, I would recommend looking into mochiweb project for pretty conversion of floats to lists. In particular, the [mochinum](https://github.com/basho/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochinum.erl) module:

```
> M = 37.5,
> mochinum:digits(M).
"37.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

@chops has a great answer, IMO (using mochinum:digits/1), but you might also get something out of looking at the io_lib module. For example:

```
8> io_lib:format("~.2f",[37.5]).
 ["37.50"]

9> io_lib:format("~.1f",[37.5]).
 ["37.5"]
```

I realize this might not be exactly what you are looking for, and in this case I think looking at/using the mochinum module is an efficient way to go, but io_lib is often overlooked and provides a really useful set of functions for formatting lists / strings